# how to delete taggregate_temp_ tables at once?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In MySQL, I have multiple tables named like this:

```
taggregate_temp_1364792160
taggregate_temp_1364795760
taggregate_temp_1364799360
taggregate_temp_1364802960
taggregate_temp_1364806560
taggregate_temp_1364810160
taggregate_temp_1364813760
taggregate_temp_1364817360
taggregate_temp_1364820960
taggregate_temp_1364824560
taggregate_temp_1364828160
taggregate_temp_1364831760
taggregate_temp_1364835360
taggregate_temp_1364838960
taggregate_temp_1364842560
taggregate_temp_1364846160
taggregate_temp_1364849760
taggregate_temp_1364853360
```

I need to delete all tables begin with: taggregate_temp_ at once

Answer (score 0):

If all the temp tables are in `mydb`, run the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name)),';')
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='mydb'
AND table_name like 'taggregate_temp%';
PREPARE s1 FROM @dropcmd; EXECUTE s1; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
```

I have done the [same technique in another post of mine in the DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/mysql-drop-table-starting-with-a-prefix/1369#1369). That post also has a demonstration of the code's execution.

## Give it a Try !!!